# Select All distinct values in a column using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012, csv, asp.net-web-api

I created a Web Api in VS 2012.
I am trying to get all the value from one column "Category", that is all the unique value, I don't want the list to be returned with duplicates.

I used this code to get products in a particular category. How do I get a full list of categories (All the unique values in the Category Column)?

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByCategory(string category)
    {
        return repository.GetAllProducts().Where(
            p => string.Equals(p.Category, category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
```

Comment: your question is not clear to me, when you `get products by category`, of course the `products` you got should have the same `category`, what's distinct here?

Comment: Yes, This code was used to get products by a specified category, but I would like to modify this to get the full list of categories. GetCatgoriesList(). Category is a column in the product table, so there would be duplicate values in the column as it relates to each product. I want the list of categories that are use to categorize products int he table.

Comment: If so the answer below should work, but with a note that the return result is an `IEnumerable<string>` which you can iterate through to print the full list of `distinct Categories`.

Comment: public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllCategory()
        {
            return repository.GetAllProducts()
                                     .Select(p => p.Category).Distinct();
        }   -- I tries this and I still get the build error

Comment: You have to change `public IEnumerable<Product>` to `public IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: This is the purpose of relational databases! Design and use a `Category` model/table.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

To have unique Categories:

```
var uniqueCategories = repository.GetAllProducts()
                                 .Select(p => p.Category)
                                 .Distinct();
```

Comment: I tried this but I get a build error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TestService.Models.Product>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Tester See King King comment on the question

Comment: Fantastic, this worked for me, I was able to select a distinct Category list from a duplicate data!!! Many Thanks

Answer (score 31):

```
var uniq = allvalues.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(y=>y.First()).Distinct();
```

Easy and simple

Comment: This seems to be better method when working with Ienumerables / Lists. This worked for me: var details = allDetails
                        .Where(x => x.EmpId == 100)
                        .GroupBy(x => x.SaleDate).Select(y => y.First()).Distinct();

Comment: Great solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have to find distinct rows with the following details 
class : Scountry
columns: countryID, countryName,isactive
There is no primary key in this. I have succeeded with the followin queries

```
public DbSet<SCountry> country { get; set; }
    public List<SCountry> DoDistinct()
    {
        var query = (from m in country group m by new { m.CountryID, m.CountryName, m.isactive } into mygroup select mygroup.FirstOrDefault()).Distinct();
        var Countries = query.ToList().Select(m => new SCountry { CountryID = m.CountryID, CountryName = m.CountryName, isactive = m.isactive }).ToList();
        return Countries;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough I tried both of these in LinqPad and the variant using group from Dmitry Gribkov by appears to be quicker. (also the final distinct is not required as the result is already distinct.

My (somewhat simple) code was:

```
public class Pair 
{ 
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string Arb {get;set;}
}

void Main()
{

    var theList = new List<Pair>();
    var randomiser = new Random();
    for (int count = 1; count < 10000; count++)
    {
        theList.Add(new Pair 
        {
            id = randomiser.Next(1, 50),
            Arb = "not used"
        });
    }

    var timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    var distinct = theList.GroupBy(c => c.id).Select(p => p.First().id);
    timer.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed);

    timer.Start();
    var otherDistinct = theList.Select(p => p.id).Distinct();
    timer.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed);
}
```